# Is Ruth Bader Ginsburg alive as of February 2019?

Tags: politics, mortality, celebrities

Right wing sources on social media have been abuzz with rumors that Ginsburg has died. The conspiracy theory is that Democrats are hiding her death to avoid another Trump pick on the Supreme Court. This conspiracy theory has been documented in mainstream media ([here](https://www.newsweek.com/ruth-bader-ginsburg-death-rumors-proliferated-online-qanon-former-trump-1314168) and [here](https://www.salon.com/2019/02/01/former-trump-staffer-spreads-gross-qanon-conspiracy-theory-that-ruth-bader-ginsburg-is-secretly-dead_partner/), among others). There's even a hashtag on Twitter for this conspiracy theory, #WheresRuth.

Yesterday The Washington Post ran a [story](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/courts_law/ruth-bader-ginsburg-makes-first-public-appearance-since-cancer-surgery/2019/02/04/251d59f4-28cf-11e9-b2fc-721718903bfc_story.html) claiming Ginsburg had attended a performance celebrating her. However, the paper featured no hard evidence that she was there and far-right sources claimed the story was fabricated.

My belief is that this is another Pizzagate- or Q-esque invention; nonetheless I don't have any proof. So is Ginsburg alive?

Comment: FYI: [she's irrefutably returned](https://www.cnn.com/2019/02/19/politics/ruth-bader-ginsburg-supreme-court-arguments/index.html)

Comment: @LordFarquaad Back from the dead I presume!

Comment: #Necromancergate

Answer (score 24):

In [this](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/02/05/ginsburg-makes-first-public-appearance-since-cancer-surgery.html) article by the well-respected Associated Press, we read of a concert that Justice Ginsburg attended Monday night (Feb 4, 2019), her first public appearance since surgery in New York on December 21, 2018.

> The justice sat in the back of the darkened auditorium at the National Museum of Women in the Arts. The National Constitution Center, which sponsored the concert, did not permit photography.

Justice Ginsburg's son James Ginsburg was also in attendance at the concert.  He told reporters that "his mother is walking a mile a day and meeting with her personal trainer twice a week."

### EDIT

Is this enough to answer the question?

To find the best explanation, I look for one that makes sense, makes the most of the evidence, and requires the least imagination on my part.

In the present case, the hypothesis doesn't make sense because it would be very hard to accomplish the coverup of the death of a US Supreme Court Justice long enough to achieve any desirable end.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89358/discussion-on-answer-by-elliot-svensson-is-ruth-bader-ginsburg-alive-as-of-febru).